# Selenium - unexpected behavior finding elements in each row

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rows

***Selenium, Chrome WebDriver, Java.***

Trying to cycle throw rows with the following code and getting unexpected behavior.

```
 List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElementsByXPath("//div[@class = \"w-dyn-items\"][contains(.//*,'2019')]/div[@class = \"w-dyn-item\"][position() < 30]")
    for (WebElement div : divs) {
        DocumentWrapper doc = new DocumentWrapper()
        try {
            //grab document stuff
            doc.title = div.findElementByXPath("//h1").getText()
            log.info("\tTitle: ${doc.title}")
            doc.dateStr = div.findElementByXPath("//div[@class=\"meta-tag\"]").getText()
            log.info("\tDate: ${doc.dateStr}")
            String google_drive_link = div.findElementByXPath("//a[@class=\"drop-link\" and contains(. ,\"PDF Agenda\")]").getAttribute('href')
            log.info("\traw Url: ${google_drive_link}")
```

The results I get is just a repeat of the same title, date and link over and over again

```
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Title: City Council & Board/Commission Meetings
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Date: DECEMBER 23, 2019
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Url: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Title: City Council & Board/Commission Meetings
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Date: DECEMBER 23, 2019
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  raw Url: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Title: City Council & Board/Commission Meetings
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Date: DECEMBER 23, 2019
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Url: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Title: City Council & Board/Commission Meetings
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Date: DECEMBER 23, 2019
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  raw Url: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Title: City Council & Board/Commission Meetings
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Date: DECEMBER 23, 2019
2019-03-18 16:47:39 [main] INFO ::  Url: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
```

Now these aren't technically table rows but a series of divs.  But shouldn't they work the same and if not can anyone explain to me why this shouldn't work?

Site I'm pulling data from https://www.cityofalhambra.org/city-meetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I read the Selenium documentation on github.io and found this..

[image]

It says we should use a dot before the XPath for a relative path.  This was my initial instinct but in previous works I've had errors using that dot.  Will try it again and update my answer.

Update* This fixed it!

```
Found document: 
    Title - City Council Public Hearing
    Date - MARCH 25, 2019
    Link - https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1aAivoeNydSf761Hmih7lHWH7rLXkhuzV
Found document: 
    Title - City Council Meeting (Regular)
    Date - MARCH 11, 2019
    Link - https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bc1MBr_M10fJOVTkQTML7LFLzz_c28HB
Found document: 
    Title - City Council (Special)
    Date - MARCH 11, 2019
    Link - https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1odnxBz6oHps5C66mHCcijx2YS_y7jgM_
Found document: 
    Title - City Council Meeting (Regular) - Business Mtg. at 5:30 p.m. & Ceremonial at 7:00 p.m.
    Date - FEBRUARY 25, 2019
    Link - https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13NBhYiRDrw2egi6iRHLgI-BlRjYIr95N
```